# How to make a website go live created using on WampServer to a given domain?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, website-hosting

I have built a website, to check its working functionalities, I used WampSever to create a local server and used phpMyAdmin for the database. But now I need to host the website on a given domain. So, how could I do that and also, how do we need to transfer the database or is there any need that a database should be present in the location or it can keep using phpMyAdmin? Kindly help me with this.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool to *access* a *MySQL* database. It is not, itself, a database. There are many different tools that can be used to view/edit a MySQL database. You need a web host with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Flagging this as blatantly off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Your website that you've built is composed of a few pieces:

1. The web server: You are running Apache with PHP.
2. The files: You have written .php, .html, and most likely .css and .js files
3. The database: You are using MySQL (phpMyAdmin is not the database, it's merely a client).

All three of these pieces need to be present on the server behind your "domain". You need to insure that your web host is running apache and php. You need to insure that your web host is running a mysql server. You will need to upload your files to your web host/server. And you will need to figure out how to get your MySQL database, tables, and possibly data migrated to the web host's mysql instance.

The trickiest part here is the MySQL component, but generally with the phpMyAdmin you can create a database dump (.sql) file that can then be used to migrate to your web host's mysql instance.

It's impossible to give particulars about how this will look for your web host as each web host is different.